# passing dict of dict between process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I can't pass a dict of dict between processes with multiprocessing in Python2.7

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

class TestProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, d, w):
        super(TestProcess, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.d = d
        self.w = w

    def run(self):
        self.d['a'][self.w] = self.w


class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        manager = Manager()
        self.d = manager.dict()
        self.d['a'] = {}

        p = TestProcess(d=self.d, w=1)
        p.start()
        p.join()

        p = TestProcess(d=self.d, w=2)
        p.start()
        p.join()

    def show(self):
        print(self.d)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t=Test()
    t.show()
```

Expecting result: {'a': {1:1, 2:2}}, but got {'a': {}} instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the nested dictionary a proxy object too:

```
manager = Manager()
self.d = manager.dict()
self.d['a'] = manager.dict()
```

or retrieve `self.d['a']`, mutate that object, and set it back:

```
a = self.d['a']
a[self.w] = self.w
self.d['a'] = a
```

`self.d` is not a regular dictionary; it wraps a dict to track mutations to the object itself, but your *value*, associated with the key `'a'` is not such an object, so mutations to that object are not detected, and the changes are not communicated with the parent process.

If you were to use `self.d['a'][self.w] = self.w`, then `self.d['a'] = self.d['a']` the latter would *retrieve the still empty dictionary from the parent process* and set `self.d['a']` back to that empty object; you *have* to create a local reference to the remote mutable nested dictionary first to ensure you correctly tell the parent process to correctly set it.

From the [*Proxy Objects* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects) of the documentation:

> If standard (non-proxy) list or dict objects are contained in a referent, modifications to those mutable values will not be propagated through the manager because the proxy has no way of knowing when the values contained within are modified. However, storing a value in a container proxy (which triggers a `__setitem__` on the proxy object) does propagate through the manager and so to effectively modify such an item, one could re-assign the modified value to the container proxy:
>
> ```
> # create a list proxy and append a mutable object (a dictionary)
> lproxy = manager.list()
> lproxy.append({})
> # now mutate the dictionary
> d = lproxy[0]
> d['a'] = 1
> d['b'] = 2
> # at this point, the changes to d are not yet synced, but by
> # updating the dictionary, the proxy is notified of the change
> lproxy[0] = d
> ```

Comment: Using self.d['a'] = self.d['a'] in the run method doesn't change anything. But using a nested dict self.d['a']=manager.dict(), and in the run d = self.d['a']
        d[self.w] = self.w
        self.d['a'] = d make the trick.

Comment: @LionelRoubeyrie: you need to do the assignment *after* mutating `self.d['a'][self.w]`.

Comment: Yes I did at the end of the run

Comment: @LionelRoubeyrie: figured out the sequence of events and updated. `self.d['a'] = self.d['a']` first retrieves the still empty dictionary from the parent process; I didn't quite realise to what extend `dict.__getitem__` is proxied *too*.